# Spring Data : Java configuration for MongoDB without XML

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I tried the [Spring Guide Accessing Data with MongoDB](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/). What I can't figure out is how do I configure my code to not use the default server address and not use the default database. I have seen many ways to do it with XML but I am trying to stay with fully XML-less configurations.

Does anyone have an example that sets the server and database without XML and can be easily integrated into the sample they show in the Spring Guide?

Note: I did find how to set the collection (search for the phrase "Which collection will my documents be saved into " [on this page](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/).

Thank you!

p.s. same story with the Spring Guide for JPA -- how do you configure the db properties -- but that is another post :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It would be something like this for a basic configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories
public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "dataBaseName";
    }

    @Override
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
        return new MongoClient("127.0.0.1", 27017);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getMappingBasePackage() {
        return "foo.bar.domain";
    }
}
```

Example for a document :

```
@Document
public class Person {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Example for a repository :

```
@Repository
public class PersonRepository {

    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public long countAllPersons() {
        return mongoTemplate.count(null, Person.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that explained it! I am sorry I can not do a "Vote Up" as I don't have enough reputation points (requires 15) -- but I did mark the answer as answered.

Comment: Does this script work with cloud foundry? Mine works locally, but when i push to to cloud foundry it cant establish the connection